# Class method to return multiple results (lists and multi-dimensional arrays)

Tags: c#, class, methods

I have a class with a method that generates some results and populates both a List and a double[,]. So when doing the calculations, final results are stored into a double[,] but intermediate results in a List.

Something like this:

```
public double[,] methodOne(Dictionary<string, double> myInputOne, List<double> myInputTwo)
{
List<double> intermediateResults= new List<double>();
double[,] finalResults= new double[rows, cols];

// Do some calculation using myInputOne and myInputTwo

intermediateResults.Add(something);

// Continue the calculation using also intermediateResults
// store results in double[,] finalResults

return results ;
}
```

This would work only if you want the method to return the results table. But how can I tell the method to return also the List intermediateResults?

I would like this method to return both the intermediate and final results so that they can be used by other methods down the road. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to return intermediate result? Are you going to keep on adding stuff to that list?

Comment: The intermediate results from this method will be used by another class later.

Comment: Maybe you should consider `out` parameter https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than return a single type or a tuple, return a custom object as it will make the calling code more readable:

```
public class Results
{
    public List<double> IntermediateResults { get; set; }
    public double[,] FinalResults { get; set; }
}
```

Then your method looks something like:

```
public Results methodOne(Dictionary<string, double> myInputOne, List<double> myInputTwo)
{
   List<double> intermediateResults = new List<double>();
   double[,] finalResults = new double[rows, cols];

   // Do some calculation using myInputOne and myInputTwo

   intermediateResults.Add(something);

   // Continue the calculation using also intermediateResults
   // store results in double[,] finalResults

   var results = new Results();
   results.FinalResult = finalResult;
   results.IntermediateResults = intermediateResults;

   return results;
}
```

Comment: This is very interesting. What method is better and more efficient between this and the one that Dasanko suggested below? Thank you.

Comment: I think efficiency in this instance is negligible, maintainable and readable code is what matters here. You can easily extend the Results object to add more properties if need be and not have to change the declaration. Also the calling code is more readable since you are using nicely named properties which make sense. Tuples are best used internally.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the return type to `Tuple<T1, T2>`

So the method declaration would become

```
public Tuple<List<double>, double[,]> methodOne(Dictionary<string, double> myInputOne, List<double> myInputTwo)
```

And in turn, you would return

```
return new Tuple<List<double>, double[,]>(intermediateResults, finalResults);
```

However, it depends on how you want to use the returned data. If it's not just a short-term result, you're better off just making a custom object, as Ralph Willgoss suggested.

Comment: Thank you. What is the advantage of this method over the one suggested byRalph Willgoss in the other answer?

Comment: Tuples are best used internally if you have private methods returning results, which are then aggregated into a public class to be exposed on the public method.

Comment: This is subjective, but I prefer returning Tuples when I know it's going to be short-lived/temporary values that will probably get used once for something else and then discarded - to me, it feels less clogging than creating a struct or a class for a one time only thing.

Answer (score 1):

An option to the other provided answers would be the [out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx)-keyword. In your case:

```
public double[,] methodOne(Dictionary<string, double> myInputOne, 
    List<double> myInputTwo, out List<double> intermediateResults)
{
    intermediateResults= new List<double>();
    double[,] finalResults= new double[rows, cols];

    // Do some calculation using myInputOne and myInputTwo

    intermediateResults.Add(something);

    // Continue the calculation using also intermediateResults
    // store results in double[,] finalResults

    return results ;
}
```

Usage:

```
List<double> intermediateResults;
double[,] finalResults = methodOne(someDictionary, someList, out intermediateResults);
```